# Convert a php get_the_term_list result to a number

Tags: php, numbers, taxonomy

I have the necessity to convert the result of a get_the_term_list to a number. I need to turn the result into a serie of icons that represent it.
Example: if the result is 5 I have to publish 5 hearts.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<?php
$showing = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'show', '', ', ', '' );
$number = (int) $showing;
for ($var = 0; $var < $number; $var++) {echo '♡';}
?>
```

but it doesn't work. The var $showing's value is always 0.
If I try to change the var $showing with a number it works perfectly.

```
<?php
$number = 5;
for ($var = 0; $var < $number; $var++) {echo '♡';}
?>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Wordpress function [get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) returns a HTML formatted string.

If you use [get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead, you get an array and you can take its size and get the desired(?) number.